# List Trigger Event Error

Tags: c#

i have a code:

```
    public class _clientSockets<Socket> : List<Socket>
    {
        public event EventHandler OnAdd;

        public void Add(Socket s)
        {
            if (OnAdd != null)
                OnAdd(this, null);
            base.Add(s);
        }
    }
```

that every client that will try to connect to the server will be stored on the list. And i tried to call it using this code:

```
     _clientSockets<Socket> s = new _clientSockets<Socket>();
     s.OnAdd += new EventHandler(clientAlerted);
     s.Add(socket);
```

But the problem is got an error something like:
" MainWindow._clientSockets.Add(Socket)' hides inherited member 'System.Collections.generic.List.Add(Socket)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. "

How can i solve this stuff? :)

Comment: or inherit from `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`. ObservableCollection has mechanisms to work with changes...

Answer (score 0):

> How can i solve this?

Either don't call your method `Add` or don't inherit from `List`.  You may find that *composition* works better than *inheritance* here, since clients could just treat your class as a plain `List<T>` and bypass your "new" `Add` method.